# g++ compilation issues on Mavericks

Tags: c++, g++, osx-mavericks

I use ezlogger library for logging for our project. After upgrading OSX Maverick I can't compile the code, the g++ compiler throws errors while compiling the logging macros. The error message:

```
In file included from ./../ezlogger/ezlogger_headers.hpp:16:
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:113:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_verbosity_level_tolerance'
                        if (m_verbosity_level <= get_verbosity_level_tolerance())
                                                 ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:118:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_log_stream'
                                        get_log_stream() << Data;
                                        ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:124:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_verbosity_level_tolerance'
                        if (m_verbosity_level <= get_verbosity_level_tolerance())
                                                 ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:129:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_log_stream'
                                        get_log_stream() << func;
                                        ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:135:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_verbosity_level_tolerance'
                        if (m_verbosity_level <= get_verbosity_level_tolerance())
                                                 ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:140:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_verbosity_level_tolerance'
                        if (m_verbosity_level <= get_verbosity_level_tolerance())
                                                 ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:145:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_verbosity_level_tolerance'
                        if (m_verbosity_level <= get_verbosity_level_tolerance())
                                                 ^
./../ezlogger/ezlogger.hpp:151:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'get_verbosity_level_tolerance'
                        if (m_verbosity_level <= get_verbosity_level_tolerance())
                                                 ^
```

The code for *get_verbosity_level_tolerance()* is the following:

```
    struct ezlogger_verbosity_level_policy
    {
            static inline verbosity get_verbosity_level_tolerance(){return set_or_get_verbosity_level_tolerance(true);}
            static void set_verbosity_level_tolerance(verbosity NewValue){set_or_get_verbosity_level_tolerance(false, NewValue);}
    private:
            inline static verbosity initial_verbosity_level(){return log_default_verbosity_level;}
            static verbosity set_or_get_verbosity_level_tolerance(bool GetLevel, verbosity NewValue = log_default_verbosity_level)
            {
                    static verbosity verbosity_level = initial_verbosity_level();
                    if (!GetLevel) verbosity_level = NewValue;
                    return verbosity_level;
            }
    };
```

Any thought how can we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get_verbosity_level_tolerance()** is a member of struct **ezlogger_verbosity_level_policy**.

Try calling **ezlogger_verbosity_level_policy::get_verbosity_level_tolerance()** instead of only **get_verbosity_level_tolerance()**